# Python: XPATH search within node

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have a html code that looks kind of like this (shortened);

```
<div id="activities" class="ListItems">
<h2>Standards</h2>
        <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="Title" href="http://www.google.com" >Guidelines on management</a>
                        <div class="Info">
                            <p>
                                text
                            </p>
                                <p class="Date">Status: Under development</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="DocList">
    <h3>Reports</h3>
        <p class="SupLink">+ <a href="http://www.google.com/test" >View More</a></p>
            <ul>
                <li class="pdf">
                    <a class="Title" href="document.pdf" target="_blank" >Document</a>
                    <span class="Size">
                        [1,542.3KB]
                    </span>
                    <div class="Info">
                                <p>
                                    text <a href="http://www.google.com" >Read more</a>
                                </p>
                        <p class="Date">
                            14/03/2018
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the value in 'href=' under 'a class="Title"' by using this code:

```
def sub_path02(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    url2 = []
    for node in tree.xpath('//a[@class="Title"]'):
        url2.append(node.get("href"))

    return url2
```

But I get two returns, the one under 'div class="DocList"' is also returned.

I am trying to change my xpath expressions so that I would only look within the  node but I cannot get it to work.

Could someone please help me understand how to "search" within a specific node. I have gone through multiple xpath documentations but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `//` you are already selecting all the `a` elements in the document.

To search in a specific `div` try specifying the parent with // and then use //a again to look anywhere in the div

```
//div[@class="ListItems"]//a[@class="Title"]

for node in tree.xpath('//div[@class="ListItems"]//a[@class="Title"]'):url2.append(node.get("href"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ted, amazing what fast and accurate answers you can get on StackOwerflow

Comment: @user2873939 - glad to have helped. People in Stack Overflow helped me when I was a developer. Now I am just trying to help people back. Would you mind up-voting my post and/or marking it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression to select the div with a specific `id` recursively :

```
'//div[@id="activities"]//a[@class="Title"]'
```

so :

```
def sub_path02(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    url2 = []
    for node in tree.xpath('//div[@id="activities"]//a[@class="Title"]'):
        url2.append(node.get("href"))

    return url2
```

#### Note :

It's ever better to select an *id* than a *class* because an *id* should be unique (in real life, there's sometimes bad code with multiple same *id* in the same page, but a *class* can be repeated N times)